# What part of My Visual Studio Installation is listening on port 10000?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

For no apparent reason, my instance of Visual Studio 2008 now listens on port 10000.  This happens even if no project is open.  Unfortunately, I need port 10000 for Azure development.

Any ideas about why VS is now listening on 10000?

EDIT: Could it be related to VSTS Profiling?  I was tinkering with that a few days ago and might not have restarted VS since then.  However, I see no settings related to port 10000 anywhere.

Comment: My guess would be the Azure tools.

Comment: @John:  Nope.  Uninstalling the Azure SDK & Azure Tools didn't fix this.  Something in VSTS is definitely listening on 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never got to the bottom of this.  I upgraded to Win7 and had to reinstall VS anyhow, so of course the problem went away then.

Comment: that's not nice. answer your own question and then check it without handing out up votes :-P

Answer (score 1):

what does

```
netstat -p tcp -o -b
```

say?

I'm not sure anything in Visual Studio 2008 that listens on port 10000. (You may have a plugin listening on this port though)

In any event, you should always be able to edit your service endpoints to use a different port.

Comment: Yes, that's how I learned that VS listens on 10000.  'netstat -ba' said it's VS.

Comment: hmmm... can you go to Help->About and do a copy info and paste it to a pastebin? Get a dump all the VS extensions you have running.

Comment: nevermind. bad idea unless you want to share all your product keys.

Comment: Not sure if those numbers are license keys or product IDs, but at any rate I sanitized the output before making a pastebin.  Link is in original post.

Comment: I have a different version of Azure tools which may be while I do anything bind on 10000